# Creating Names in the Name manager using reference cells

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I am trying to create a macro that will automatically make a "Name" for me (Formulas->Name Manager) and use certain cells to create the Name function.  I am having trouble with the code:

```
' offset Macro
'

Dim offsetvalue As Integer

Dim myname As String

offsetvalue = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K4").Value

myname = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K5").Value

  ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=myname, RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=OFFSET(daterange,0,offsetvalue)"
  
End Sub
```

For this section:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=myname, RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=OFFSET(daterange,0,offsetvalue)"
```

"daterange" is referring to an already existing Name in the name manager.  I want the 'offsetvalue' part of the argument to refer to the Dim offsetvalue, but instead it just puts the words 'offsetvalue' in the Name Manager.  If I remove the quotes around the entire offset function then the macro doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to concatenate the strings of the formula with the variable name: `RefersToR1C1:="=OFFSET(daterange,0," & offsetvalue & ")"` to get the value of the variable `offsetvalue`.

Comment: Thank you, figures it was something so simple.